# Dotnet Core IIS site fails with exit code 80131506

Tags: iis, .net-core

Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFDAB049857 (00007FFDAB010000) with exit code 80131506.

Comment: I've been poked by this problem twice now, as we're starting to roll out Dotnet Core sites, so hopefully googling this exit code will bring me here the next time it happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the IIS App Pool- .NET CLR Version should be "No Managed Code" for DotNet Core on IIS.